# Given $r \in \mathbb{N}$, prove there exist odd primes $p,q$ s.t. $p$ splits into $r$ primes in the $q$th cyclotomic field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

> Given $r \in \mathbb{N}$, prove there exist odd primes $p,q$ s.t. $p$ splits into $r$ primes in the $q$th cyclotomic field.

---

Let $\omega = e^{2\pi i /q}$.  Then I know that $(p,q) = 1 \implies p \nmid \text{disc}(\omega)$ so $p$ is unramified, implying that I simply need to assure that $f = \frac{q - 1}{r}$.  In cyclotomic fields, $f$ is the multiplicative order of $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}^\times$; thus, I need to show that there exist odd primes $p,q$ s.t. $$ p^{\frac{q-1}{r}} \equiv 1 \pmod{q} $$

and that for any $a < \frac{q-1}{r}$, $p^a \not\equiv 1 \pmod{q}$.  I'm not sure how to make this happen, or if this even the right path; any help is appreciated.

---

**Solution** (based on the comments below):  Fix a prime $q$ s.t. $q \equiv 1 \pmod{r}$; we know such a prime exists via [Dirichlet's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).  Then since $(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is cyclic, there exists an $a \in (\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^\times$ s.t. $|a| = \frac{q-1}{r}$.  Now, invoking Dirichlet's Theorem once more, fix a prime $p$ s.t. $p \equiv a \pmod{q}$.  Then the order of $p$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is $\frac{q-1}{r}$ as desired.

Comment: By Dirichlet's Theorem on primes in Arithmetic Progressions, there are infinitely many primes $q \equiv 1$ (mod r).  Fix such a q.  Then invoke the Theorem again to find the prime p you want.

Comment: Seems OK. Since $\mathbb \Z/q\mathbb Z ^\times$ is cyclic, there exists an element, say $a$ of order $\frac{q-1}{r}$; by Dirichlet's theorem there primes congruent to $a$ mod $q$.

Comment: Great.  Thanks.  I knew it had to be something easy that I was missing.  I'll edit it into the question.